# Getting error when trying to resize an inserted image

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

**Background**

Working on a task-pane add in which is being used in word.  I current have the functionality to insert images into the word doc, however when dealing with larger documents, my function is not getting the job done correctly.  It either puts the image in the start of the document or at the end.

**Question**

I am looking for the ability to have the user select where they want the image and insert the image there.  This means that in a 10 page .docx if the user wants to place the image between two paragraphs on page three it will go there; not at the start or the end of the .docx

**Important**

I am currently using a function that allows me to give the image which I am inserting a height and width.  I will need to be able to give the images a new height and width.

**Code Block 1 - I am Using Right Now**

```
    function insertImageToDoc(base64, selectedContents) {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
            context.load(paragraphs);
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                var paragraph = paragraphs.items[0];
                var image = paragraph.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, "start");
                image.width = selectedContents.ImageWidth;
                image.height = selectedContents.Imageheight;
                return context.sync()
            });
        })
.catch(function (error) {
    feedBackMessage("Image could not be inserted, please reload and try again");
});
    }
```

**Code Block 1**

This code works well however where the insertion of the b64 happens, the only option I do have to is to either insert at "start" or "end".  This is why the users are currently experiencing the given issue when they are dealing with documents that are more than 1 page.

**Code Block 2**

```
function insertImageToDoc(base64, selectedContents) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        context.load(range)
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            var image = range.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            context.load(image);
            return context.sync().then(function () {           
                image.width = selectedContents.ImageWidth;
                image.height = selectedContents.Imageheight;
                return context.sync()
            })              
        });
    })
.catch(function (error) {
    feedBackMessage("Image could not be inserted, please reload and try again");
});
}
```

**Code Block 2**

This block is able to insert an image in any given location how ever I lose the ability of actually setting the size for the image I am inserting.  It errors out when I am applying the height and width.

**Code Block 2 Error**

[image]

**Summary**

I need the ability to insert an image in any given spot and also have the ability to resize the images height and width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after debugging and trying different methods I found the issue which was giving me the error.  @Fei , you are correct about it working with office web apps.  **For the record, the issues arouse because the image dimensions were basing the image size in inches and not in pixels when uploaded to SharePoint.**   This was causing office-js to give the error message and no resize to the dimensions which were coming in from SharePoint.

**For Example:**

[image]

As you see the information coming in from SharePoint is telling my word add in to apply `H =1050 and W = 2445` dimensions to the image.  Applying these dimensions in pixels caused the error and prevented the image from being resized.  Which makes sense.  So the root of all evil lays outside of the Office-js api.  **Meaning that both code blocks which I used as examples will work fine.**

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of `selectedContents`? The code below works well for me in **Word online**:

```
   function replaceImage() {

    var selectedContents = {};
    selectedContents.ImageWidth=20;
    selectedContents.Imageheight=80;

    var base64="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";
    insertImageToDoc(base64, selectedContents);
}

function insertImageToDoc(base64, selectedContents) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        context.load(range)
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            var image = range.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            context.load(image);
            return context.sync().then(function () {           
                image.width = selectedContents.ImageWidth;
                image.height = selectedContents.Imageheight;
                return context.sync()
            })              
        });
    })
.catch(function (error) {
    feedBackMessage("Image could not be inserted, please reload and try again");
});
}
```

Here are the steps for tested:
1. Insert an image from online
2. select the image and click the button to execute the `replaceImage` function.

In addition, what's the client you were developing?

Comment: Hey Fei you were right, I posted the root of the issue.